# Probability of drawing exactly two aces and two kings or one ace and three kings?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, inclusion-exclusion

I've been trying to calculate the probability of drawing exactly two aces and two kings, or exactly one ace and three kings when the player already has an ace in hand. The player draws 24 more cards, and the deck is full aside from the ace in hand.

I've calculated the probability of getting exactly two aces and two kings like so:

$\dfrac{{3\choose2}.{4\choose2}.{44\choose20}}{{51\choose24}} \approx 13.81\%$

Which seems a little high to me. However, moving on with the same equation for drawing exactly one ace and three kings:

$\dfrac{{3\choose1}.{4\choose3}.{44\choose20}}{{51\choose24}} \approx 9.20\%$

And so, the probability of getting one *or* the other is $13.81\% + 9.20\% = 23.01\%$.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Because I have trouble believing there's a $23.01\%$ chance of the described scenario arising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exactly two more aces and exactly two kings in 24 draws from a
deck of 51 cards (missing an ace), I also get

$$ \frac{{3 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{44 \choose 20}}{{51 \choose 24}} = 0.138,$$

(to three places), computed in R as:

```
 18*choose(44, 20)/choose(51,24)
 ## 0.1380654
```

Here is a simulation of a million such draws with probabilities
correct to 2 or 3 places.

```
 m = 10^6;  nr.ace = nr.kng = numeric(m)
 deck = 2:52 # aces are 1,2,3,4; kings 5,6.7,8
 for (i in 1:m) {
  draw = sample(deck, 24)
  nr.ace[i] = sum(match(2:4, draw, nomatch=0)>0)
  nr.kng[i] = sum(match(5:8, draw, nomatch=0)>0) }

 mean(nr.ace == 2)
 ## 0.357932
 mean(nr.kng == 2)
 ## 0.387775
 mean(nr.ace==2 & nr.kng==2)
 ## 0.137598  # approx 0.138 as in exact combinatorial result
 mean(nr.ace==1 & nr.kng==3)
 ## 0.092077

 AK = as.data.frame(cbind(nr.ace,nr.kng))
 table(AK)/m
           nr.kng
 ## nr.ace        0        1        2        3        4
 ##      0 0.007532 0.035196 0.055101 0.035380 0.007596
 ##      1 0.026295 0.109556 0.157987 0.092077 0.018387
 ##      2 0.027684 0.105594 0.137598 0.073657 0.013399
 ##      3 0.008706 0.030502 0.037089 0.017775 0.002889
```

The approximate probability of $P(A = 2, K = 2)$ is found in
cell $(2,2)$ of the table. The approximate probability $P(A = 1, K = 3)$ is in cell $(1, 3).$

Related probabilities can also be approximated from the table.
For example, the total probability 
$P(A = 2) \approx 0.358$ is found separately in the printout
above and as the total of row 2 of the table.

```
 sum(c(0.027684, 0.105594, 0.137598, 0.073657, 0.013399))
 ## 0.357932
```

Its exact
probability (to three places) is

$$ \frac{{3 \choose 2}{48 \choose 23}}{{51 \choose 24}} = 0.358,$$

```
 3*choose(48, 22)/choose(51, 24)
 ## 0.3578391
```

However, to get the probability of either 'two aces and two kings' OR
'one ace and three kings', you should *add only two* entries in
the table $(2,2)$ and $(1,3).$

**Addendum:** 'Expanded' R code, demonstrating method of counting aces (cards 2 through 4) in 24 draws:

```
 draw = sample(deck, 24);  draw  # list of 24 cards drawn w/o replacement
 ## 17 40 46 51 44 30 50 24  4  7 52 31 13 28 25 18 22 42  3  5 43 48 19  8
 ace.posn = match(2:4, draw, nomatch=0);  ace.posn
 ## 0 19  9  # card 2 not drawn, 19th was card 3, 9th was card 4
 tf.aces = (ace.posn > 0);  tf.aces
 ## FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  # TRUE for each ace found
 nr.aces = sum(tf.aces);  nr.aces  # counts TRUE's
 ## 2  # count of aces in 'draw' is stored in vector 'nr.ace'
```

The *count* of the number of aces in a 'draw' does not depend on which aces or their order. This is done a million times.

Comment: I'm not sure what all that test data means, but are you saying $23.01\%$ is correct, or incorrect?

Comment: Trying again to add my reply, browser lost the 1st attempt. Yes, 0.23 is correct. Add two cells from my table. (They agree with the first two combinatorial results in your question.) I don't see any double-counting in that. See the last sentence of my answer, added recently. – BruceET

Comment: I see. So it must be right, but it seems weird that there are such high odds for an "exact" scenario, doesn't it? I'm actually adding the odds for exactly one more ace and 2 of **any** other card (and I'm doing the same for exactly 2 more aces). The problem I'm running into is the massive amount of double-counting. Can you think of a more suitable algorithm for this?

Comment: I think that'll be messy. I think surprisingly high probabilities in your original problem are because you are drawing 24 cards. Intuition from 5-card poker and 13-card bridge does not carry over.

Comment: If you use the same formula as OP, obviously you will get a similar result by simulation.

Comment: @trublueanil: The simulation actually counts the outcomes in each draw of 24 cards without regard to order. Quite separately, my use of OPs formula was only for comparison.

Comment: How does your simulation distinguish between $(i)$ I have a **particular** ace in hand (say the ace of apades), and draw two more aces, etc. $(ii)$ I have an unknown ace in hand and draw two more aces, etc. My contention is that OP's answer is correct only for $(i)$

Comment: Nr. 1 in my list `2:52` is missing. (In a real situation I could look at it and know which one.) Denominator of OP's formula is also for 51-card deck. So, yes, I agree OP and I are both assuming a particular known ace is missing from the deck.Thanks for clarification. (+1, but the -1 wasn't mine).

Comment: I rethought the issue, and find that even if we do not assume that a particular ace is missing, the result will be the same. I have revised my answer accordingly. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Revised answer**

Assuming you are respectively drawing $2$ or $1$ *more* aces, your answers are correct.

My suspicion that the first ace being unspecified would affect the result was unwarranted.

Here is a longer way for the first case (just to confirm the correctness).

The ace you have could be any of $4$, so numerator $= 4\times{3 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{44 \choose 20}$

But then you need to similarly structure the denominator as $4\times\binom{51}{24}$,

and the result will remain the same as what you got.

Comment: Hmm.. Would you mind elaborating? I believe you that I've overcounted, but I'm having trouble figuring out why I need to divide..

Comment: I am easily confused by combinatorial problems, but I too am puzzled by this analysis of overcounting.

Comment: Denominator count is unordered. In numerator, C(3,2) = 3.

Comment: I have reconsidered the queries raised, and concluded that there is no overcounting.